# In Laravel, how can I have "with" return a boolean instead of the object, true in case it exists, false if doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, collections

For example, we have a songs table, and a favorites (songs) table.

If I use `Songs::with('favorites')->get()`, it will return as follows:

```
"songs": [
  {
    "id": 43,
    "name": "Song 1",
    "favorites": [
      {
        "id": 52,
        "user_id": 25,
        "song_id": 43
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 44,
    "name": "Song 2",
    "favorites": []
  },
```

What I want to do is, in case the song has been favorited, return 1, and if not, return 0, as follows:

```
  {
    "id": 43,
    "name": "Song 1",
    "favorites": true                (or 1)
  },
  {
    "id": 44,
    "name": "Song 2",
    "favorites": false              (or 0)
  },
```

Is there a way to do it without having to run through the returned collection array manually in PHP?

Comment: and you don't want to use `map`?

Comment: Anyway seems you already have what you want. If $song->favorites is null (false) and if not, true.

Comment: Doesn't map just iterate over the result set? I was hoping to do something before/wile the model is loaded in the query.

Comment: @Lucas yeah, you're correct. It's possible to leave it as is. Just a curiosity of mine to change it.

Comment: You can also use a more raw SQL approach to do that, but I not have sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a raw SQL approach

```
DB::select('SELECT s.*, (CASE WHEN f.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as favorites FROM songs s LEFT JOIN favorites f ON s.id = f.song_id GROUP BY s.id')
```

will return the following structure:

```
[
  StdClass { 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'Song 1', 'favorites' => 1 },
  StdClass { 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'Song 2', 'favorites' => 0 },
  StdClass { 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'Song 3', 'favorites' => 1 },
]
```

Now, using Eloquent

```
Song::withCount('favorites')->get()
```

will return the an array of objects of the Song class

```
[
  Song { 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'Song 1', 'favorites_count' => 1 },
  Song { 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'Song 2', 'favorites_count' => 0 },
  Song { 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'Song 3', 'favorites_count' => 3 }
]
```

The difference is the first will return an array of PHP standard objects while the second an array of Song objects and the first is **faster** than second.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the simplest solution using Eloquent

```
Song::withCount([
    'favorites' => function ($query) {
         $query->select(DB::raw('IF(count(*) > 0, 1, 0)'));
    }
])->orderBy('favorites_count', 'desc');
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of different ways to do what you want, it all depends on what works best for you.

If you want the result returned in your result set, you can setup a scope:

```
class Song extends Model
{
    public function scopeAddFavorite($query, $userId = null)
    {
        $andUser = !empty($userId) ? ' AND favorites.user_id = '.$userId : '';
        return $query->addSelect(\DB::raw('(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM favorites WHERE favorites.song_id = songs.id'.$andUser.')) as is_favorite')); 
    }
}
```

Since this scope modifies the 'select' statement, you need to make sure to manually specify the other columns you want before adding in the scope.

```
$songs = Song::select('*')->addFavorite()->get();
```

I added in the ability to pass in the user id, in case you wanted to specify that the column only return true if the song has been favorited by a specific user.

```
$songs = Song::select('*')->addFavorite(25)->get();
```

---

Another option, you can add an accessor to your model that will handle the check for you. You can [read about accessors here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).

```
class Song extends Model
{
    // only do this if you want to include is_favorite in your json output by default
    protected $appends = ['is_favorite'];

    public function getIsFavoriteAttribute()
    {
        // if you always want to hit the database:
        return $this->favorites()->count() > 0;

        // if you're okay using any pre-loaded relationship
        // will load the relationship if it doesn't exist
        return $this->favorites->count() > 0;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$song = Song::find(1);

// access is_favorite like a normal attribute
var_dump($song->is_favorite);

// with $appends, will show is_favorite;
// without $appends, will not show is_favorite
var_dump($song);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do something like this without somehow manipulating the original results object first.

You don't really specify how you need to use or iterate through the data, but maybe [Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) can help you? Either way you'll need to iterate over the data once to manipulate it. A high order function like `map` will help you do this.

Comment: Scopes will only return the ones with favorites or the ones without favorites. I'm looking for something like mutators, but for results returned with 'with'.

Comment: Doesn't map just iterate over the result set? I was hoping to do something before/wile the model is loaded in the query. But I suppose such a thing is not really possible with eloquent alone.

Comment: `each` is just an iterator. `map` allows you to iterate and do some manipulation from a callback into a new variable. [see docs for map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-map)

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have the $songs array, you can do this,

```
foreach($songs as $song)
    $song["favorites"] = is_null($song["favorites"]) ? true : false;
```